Замена стандартной метки на карте яндекс апи 3.0
изначальный код не могу скинуть, у меня он куском вставляется, а не полностью,
вот код метки:
Добавляем слой объектов map.addChild(new YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer()) // Подключение модуля меток const {YMapDefaultMarker} = (await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-markers@0.0.1')); // Создание метки const myPlacemark = new YMapDefaultMarker({ "coordinates": [135.5,-25.5], "color": "red", "title": "Австралия", "subtitle": "Это Австралия" }); Добавление метки на карту map.addChild(myPlacemark);
во первых хотелось бы понять, что это за импорт, @yandex/ymaps3-markers@0.0.1', в документации ничего не нашел, как можно было самому к этому прийти? если бы мне в прошлом моем вопросе не скинули шаблон подключения метки, я бы никогда не смог бы прийти к этому
но ладно, основная суть не в этом, как мне поменять дефолтную метку на свою svg?
еще был вопрос, как окошко с текстом(title, subtitle) расположить допустим над меткой или под меткой, как то возможно есть варианты поменять его расположение, я к сожалению не смог найти других способов, кроме как напрямую воздействовать на нее через css, но буду также рад узнать, как это сделать непосредственно через библиотеку

Для стандартной метки, о которой изначально шла речь, нужно подключать пакет @yandex/ymaps3-markers@0.0.1. Ссылка на него есть в разделе Пакеты JS API справки. Эта метка не подразумевает пользовательских модификаций её внешнего вида.
Если вам нужны группы меток с уникальным внешним видом, вам следует использовать подход, описанный в нашем примере Добавление маркера с пользовательским изображением на карту.

честно говоря надеялся на более емкий и полный ответ, чем рекомендация обратиться к сырой и непонятной документации, в которую я безуспешно неоднократно заглядывал, спасибо
